# Android NDK How to use armeabi static library with multi architecture App?

Tags: android, c++, architecture, android-ndk, .so

My Android App contain a.so library for All Architecture in same build and i want to include b.so library into my project but its have only one architecture like armeabi how to include this library to my project.

Comment: Details depend on which build process you are using?  General case is just to copy `b.so` into the ABI folder that gets included in the build packaging step for your APK.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `b.so` into folder with proper name (`armeabi` in your case). But note, that your app won't work on another architectures like `x86`, `mips` so on. You should build that `b.so` for each arch that you are interested in.